# Laravel not creating autoload.php in vendor folder?

Tags: php, laravel

Not sure why but when running `laravel new` inside a directory, it makes the app but doesn't make the `autoload.php` file?

I've tried running this

```
composer dump-autoload
```

After running the above command Laravel seems to throw a 500 error page. I've tried other things like `composer update`, `composer install`

Running such a command resulted in this

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file
Package operations: 37 installs, 0 updates, 0 removals
  - Installing jakub-onderka/php-console-highlighter (v0.4): Loading from cache

    Invalid zip file, retrying...
  - Installing jakub-onderka/php-console-highlighter (v0.4): Loading from cache

    Invalid zip file, retrying...
  - Installing jakub-onderka/php-console-highlighter (v0.4): Loading from cache
    Failed to download jakub-onderka/php-console-highlighter from dist: 'C:\Users\ash\Desktop\workspace\projects\gaming-site\vendor/jakub-onderka/php-console-highlighter/6664f6e733cabe83723c2d19f66a4784' is not a zip archive.
    Now trying to download from source
  - Installing jakub-onderka/php-console-highlighter (v0.4): Cloning 9f7a229a69


  [RuntimeException]
  Failed to clone https://github.com/JakubOnderka/PHP-Console-Highlighter.git, git was not found, check that it is in
  stalled and in your PATH env.

  'git' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
  operable program or batch file.


install [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--dry-run] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--no-custom-installers] [--no-autoloader] [--no-scripts] [--no-progress] [--no-suggest] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [-a|--classmap-authoritative] [--apcu-autoloader] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--] [<packages>]...
```

I don't see why its requiring git now, it didn't in the initial install process. Am I doing something wrong? This seems very strange for composer.

I've even tried running it like this, no luck:

```
composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel
```

Answer (score 2):

Git is a tool used by many developers to pull the required files in order for their app to work.

Just head on to [git-scm.com](https://git-scm.com/) and install git.

I believe that you cannot use laravel without git installed on your system.

On this case, laravel is trying to download a PHP Console Highlighter which was hosted on github.com. It uses a "git clone" command to get a copy of that repository. That is why you need to install git.

Answer (score 2):

Git is a revision control system used to track changes in computer files. It's a tool to manage your code & file history while co-ordinating work remotely on those files with others.
Just install git and get going.
You can download it at www.git-scm.com
With laravel 5.7 version you will need git